# Initializing Firebase in a different process (in multi-process app) does not work

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Posted this in the Google firebase-talk group, but there's been no response so posting here:

I'm trying to offload Firebase messaging into a standalone process in my app, different from the main app process. I've read this [blog by Doug Stevenson](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html) which says that Firebase is initialized by default in the main process of an application using ContentProviders (FirebaseInitProvider).

This earlier conversation in this group seemed to suggest that initializing Firebase in a secondary process should work:
"ContentProviders aren't created in other processes, so you will have to manually init Firebase in your other processes in order to make use of Firebase features.  I have not tried this myself yet, but my understanding is that you should do this via the FirebaseApp singleton using its `initializeApp()` function that takes three args.  You'll need to arrange for this to happen at the entry point for your component that expects to run in another process.
"
Here's what I tried:

- I created a `FirebaseListenerService` which extends `FirebaseMessagingService` and added this to the manifest to come up in a secondary process:

```
<service
  android:name=".xxx.yyy.FirebaseListenerService"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:process="secondary"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

- In this FirebaseListenerService I override the onCreate function and initialize the FirebaseApp here:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  FirebaseApp.initialize(/** context */, /** options */);
}
```

I can see the "secondary" process starting up correctly.
I also see the onCreate() getting called.
However I do not see the FirebaseListenerService receive any messages via onMessageReceived()

I believe this should work in theory, but as Doug mentioned in the conversations before bringing up Firebase in a secondary process is not well tested, so I'm curious if it's some limitation within Firebase SDK itself that's causing this. Any help on this is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I didn't find any solution, because FirebaseMessagingService aparently runs only on main thread.

But I found a way to fix my problem temporaly. Simply call any broadcast receiver (running in the "secondary" process)

```
val intent = Intent(this, SomeBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
intent.putExtra("action", "some action")
sendBroadcast(intent)
```

This BroadcastReceiver can interact with other classes in same process, even though it was called by the main process.

Hope its helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Firebase Message calls onMessageReceived() only on particular conditions.

1. received data has "bypass_proxy_notification" flag set (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidNotification)
2. received data contains only payload
3. process where Service is running is on foreground and received data has notification to handle

In user case, if secondary process is not the same process where activity is running that is expected behavior.